# While Parallelizing QuickSort in Java, Threads never returns back at join(). Why?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, quicksort

I am having simple code of paralellizing QuickSort algorithm in Java, in run method I everytime create two seperate new threads for parallelizing processing of Array elements. But as it encounters join() statements for both created threads, threads never backs and halts on joins(), seems join() never releases them.

Below is the code.

```
class StartJoinQuickSort implements Runnable 
{
    private int m_Low, m_High;
    private int[] m_Array = null;

    private final static int NR_OF_VALUES = 10; // TOTAL_NO_VALUES
    private int PivotElement;   
    private static Random m_random = new Random( );


    public StartJoinQuickSort(int[] a_Array,int a_Low,int a_High)
    {
        this.m_Array = a_Array;
        this.m_Low = a_Low;
        this.m_High = a_High;
    }
    private void SwapArrayElements(int a_i,int a_j)
    {
        int temp = this.m_Array[a_i];
        this.m_Array[a_i] = this.m_Array[a_j];
        this.m_Array[a_j] = temp;

    }// end of SwapArrayElements

    private static int nextRandomFunctionValue(int aStart, int aEnd)
    {
        if ( aStart > aEnd )
        {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Start cannot exceed End.");
        }

        //get the range, casting to long to avoid overflow problems
        long range = (long)aEnd - (long)aStart + 1;

        // compute a fraction of the range, 0 <= frac < range

        long fraction = (long)(range * m_random.nextDouble());
        int randomNumber =  (int)(fraction + aStart);    
        return randomNumber;

    }// end of nextRandomFunctionValue

    private static int[] GetArrayWithRandomValues()
    {
        int[] ArrayToBePopulatedWithRandomValues  = new int[NR_OF_VALUES];
        for(int index =0; index<NR_OF_VALUES;index++)
        {
            int RandomValue = StartJoinQuickSort.nextRandomFunctionValue(0,NR_OF_VALUES);
            ArrayToBePopulatedWithRandomValues[index] =  RandomValue;

        }//end of for

        return ArrayToBePopulatedWithRandomValues;

    }//end of GetArrayWithRandomValues
    private int middleIndex(int left, int right) 
    {
        return left + (right - left) / 2;
    }
    public int Partition(int a_Start,int a_end)
    {
    //  System.out.println("Partition ..thId : " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        int pivotIndex = 0;

        int i = a_Start;
        int j = a_end;

        try
        {
            pivotIndex = middleIndex(a_Start , a_end);
            this.PivotElement = this.m_Array[pivotIndex];

            do
            {
                while(this.m_Array[i] < PivotElement )
                    i++;

                if(j>0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        while( this.m_Array[j] > PivotElement )
                            j--;
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(" j : " + j);}

                }//end of if

                if(i<=j)
                {
                    SwapArrayElements(i,j);

                //  System.out.println("Swap .." + + Thread.currentThread().getId());

                    i++;
                    j--;

                }//end of if

            }while(i<=j);
        }
        catch(Exception except)
        {
            System.out.println("exception in Partition " + except);
        }
        return j;
    }

    public void run()  
    {

        //System.out.println("in run..");


        //System.out.println("after PARTITION");

        StartJoinQuickSort oStartQuickSort_1 = null;
        StartJoinQuickSort oStartQuickSort_2 = null;



        if(this.m_Low < this.m_High )
        {
            int Index = Partition(this.m_Low,this.m_High);



            Thread thPart_1 = new Thread ( new StartJoinQuickSort( this.m_Array,this.m_Low,Index ) );
            Thread thPart_2 = new Thread ( new StartJoinQuickSort( this.m_Array,Index + 1,this.m_High ) );

            thPart_1.start();   thPart_2.start();


        //}//end of if
        //if( Index + 1 < this.m_High)
        //{         
            try
            {           
                    thPart_1.join(); thPart_2.join();

            }catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace();}         
        }
    }//end of run
```

Regards
Usman

Comment: BTW, this is a very naïve way to do parallel quicksort. You'll loose more time creating all the threads than you gain from parallelizing. See http://www.deftitlenil.com/2011/04/blog-post_05.html for a solution that uses JDK7's new ForkJoinPool.

Comment: I have done with ForkJoin, But I want this part to be done ( Naive way).

Comment: I am afraid you need to show us the source code of `StartJoinQuickSort` in order for us to be able to tell why it never ends. Also the code of `Partition`.

Comment: I added whole code of QuickSort above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, it is never a good idea to implement a recursive algorithm in parallel like this. You will end up creating a huge number of threads (exponential at every level) and will eventually oversubscribe the system.

The best idea is to have a cutoff point, which let's say is equal to the number of available cores. Then when the current level of recursion has a number of branches equal to the cutoff point switch to a sequential quicksort. Some very rough pseudocode of the flow:

```
parallel_quicksort(level, interval) {
    // compute subintervals interval1, interval2
    if(level < cutoff) { 
        spawn1: parallel_quicksort(level + 1, interval1);
        spawn2: parallel_quicksort(level + 1, interval2);

        join1();     
        join2();
    } else {
        quicksort(interval1);
        quicksort(interval2);
    }
}
```

Also have a look over this implementation to see if you've missed something: http://www.inf.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/sortieren/quick/quicken.htm

Comment: Tudor thanks for advice. Can you please show me the level...? how to compute the level and pass it to quicksort procedure. cutoff point is pivot Index...Right? i mean in quicksort, the workaround is to find some pivot element and then make some recursion to procedure ( Here normally threads created for each call of QuickSort procedure), So what you mean by cutoff then? and level..? Can you show me plz some java code or understanding better.

Comment: @Usman: Well level would start at 0 when you begin the computation. Cutoff would be computed as the level where you spawn a number of threads equal to the number of your cores. So for example if you have 4 cores, your cutoff would be 1 because at level 0 you spawn 2 threads, then at level 1 each thread spawns another 2 threads so in total you have 4. You can get the number of cores with Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

Comment: A JDK7 ForkJoinPool will typically use as many threads as there are processors by default. It will then enqueue tasks following the forks and joins in your code.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you have e.g. low=0, high=1? If your Partition returns 1, you'll have an infinite loop of threads, right?

Answer (score 0):

join() blocks if your thread doesn't finish.  You need to determine why your threads are not finishing.  Can you try debugging your program with a debugger?

Comment: I only have some 50 values or somehow 100 values to sort, why not it is finishing up, this is the problem which I am facing. It just needs to Sort 50 values or 100. I debugged, it just in the processing always inside Partition for different threads. Seems it creating endlessly different threads and in a way of processing Partition. What could be the problem..

Comment: Your should be able to see that in the debugger.  You should be able to determine when it should stop creating threads.  What happens at this point and what should happen?  I would try a smaller set like 3 or 5 values as it might be easier to debug.

Comment: share the results then with little biggers like with 10 values. I m debugging some how and making some of dry runs...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your kind suggestions and advices.
I myself detected the problem. it was with Partition function which was not working fine, it was having some problems, I choose another one and it worked fine for me..

New Partition procedure is :

public int Partition(int[] a_Array, int a_Left, int a_Right)
    {
        // chose middle value of range for our pivot
        int pivotValue = a_Array[middleIndex(a_Left, a_Right)];

```
    --a_Left;
    ++a_Right;

    while (true)
    {
        do
            ++a_Left;
        while (a_Array[a_Left] < pivotValue);

        do
            --a_Right;
        while (a_Array[a_Right] > pivotValue);

        if (a_Left < a_Right)           
            SwapArrayElements(a_Left,a_Right);
        else
        {
            return a_Right;
        }
    }
}
```